# Не могу составить linq-запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список объектов со следующей структурой(что-то вроде оповещений):

```
public struct Friend
{
    public int FromUserId;

    public DateTime SendDate;

    public int Status;

    public int ToUserId;
}
```

Значение Status меняется от 0 до 3. FromUserId != ToUserId.

Я фиксирую номер какого-то юзера и хочу выбрать все объекты, удовлетворяющие условиям:

FromUserId или ToUserId объекта == номеру фиксированного мной юзера и поле Status == 2. 
Либо если есть пара объектов user1 и user2, где user1.FromUserId == user2.ToUserId и user1.ToUserId == user2.FromUserId(то есть симметричное оповещение) и какой-то из этих Id равен Id моего фиксированного пользователя, и поле status != 3, то эту пару тоже надо выбрать.

Никак не могу составить такой запрос, который бы удовлетворял моим условиям. 
Пока есть такое:

```
var tmpUserFriends =
        from potentialFriend in this.friends
        let someFriends = potentialFriend
        where ((someFriends.ToUserId == userContext.User.UserId ||
                someFriends.FromUserId == userContext.User.UserId) && someFriends.Status != 3)
        join user in this.friends on potentialFriend.ToUserId equals user.FromUserId
        where ((user.ToUserId == userContext.User.UserId ||
                user.FromUserId == userContext.User.UserId) && user.Status != 3)
        select user;
```

Где userContext.User - как раз мой фиксированный пользователь, а this.friends - это список всех объектов. Этот запрос выводит нужные мне объекты, но добавляет лишние - FromUserId или ToUserId объекта == номеру фиксированного мной юзера, но поле Status не 2, как в условии, а 0,1,2. Мне нужно только значение 2. В симметричном оповещении допускается 0,1,2.

Comment: И да, для выборки необходимо использовать только linq-запросы.

Comment: не очень понял, проблема только в этом: "но поле Status не 2, как в условии, а 0,1, 2."? так и сделайте == 2 и не будет 0,1, а только 2. а во другой части оставьте !=3

Comment: Да, проблема в этом. Но если выставить в первом условии == 2, то join будет проходить только по этим элементам. Так я не выцеплю симметричные оповещения, потому что join проходит по элементам со Status == 2, а в этом случае мне нужны еще и объекты со статусом 0 и 1. То есть в моем понимании мне нужно что-то типа двойного цикла в виде запроса организовать, чтобы симметричные пары найти. И объединить два множества - со статусом 2 и симметричные с любым статусом, отличным от 3.

Comment: можно сделать два запроса и union'ом их объединить (потому что, если честно, в столько тонкостей вникать сложно без возможности тестирования)

Comment: Да, наверное, так и правда будет легче. В идеале мне нужно сделать одним запросом, но пока попробую так. Спасибо за совет!